# Developing iOS apps on two Macs?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I develop for iPhone on my iMac. My iPhone is linked to my iMac to put music on etc through iTunes.

Will I be able to deploy test applications to the iPhone from both the iMac and a new laptop (air) with it still being linked to my iMac for music etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you develop on the other mac, you probably have Xcode and then you can directly run the app to your iPhone without unpairing your device with the first Mac. Through Xcode organizer (cmd + fn + 2) you can also drag apps without opening iTunes. It's really handy!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Simply configure your iTunes on the Air not to perform any automatic synchronization when a device is plugged in.

Comment: can you give a link from where I can learn how to do it ?

Comment: In iTunes->Preferences->Devices check "Prevent iPods, iPhones, and iPads from syncing automatically" and hit OK. Done.